# How can I get the number of bounding boxes per frame of a video?

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I'm using yolov8 for object detection.  I have trained my model to be efficient and accurate in detecting the object I'm looking for.  I'm only looking for a single object.  I'm using object detection as a way to record the lifespan of the model organism, the rotifer.    All I'm looking to do is take a video and output the number of bounding boxes (rotifers) per frame.  Preferably in .csv format with frame number in one column and the corresponding bounding box count in the neighboring column.

I have tried a number of different things but they have been unable to output in the preferred format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete this task with the following code.

```
# Set Frame to zero
current_frame = 0
# Set key value
key=0
```

```
# Loop through all files in the folder
for image in sorted(os.listdir(output_crop)):
    if image.endswith('.jpg'):
        image_path = os.path.join(output_crop, image)
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        # Run Model with however much confidence on image.
        results = model(img, conf=.19,verbose=False, max_det=5)
        counts = {}
        for result in results:
            boxes = result.boxes.cpu().numpy()
            for box in boxes:
                cls = int(box.cls[0])
                if not cls in counts.keys():
                    counts[cls] = 1
                else:
                    counts[cls] += 1
            try:
                alive = (current_frame, str(counts[key]))
            except KeyError:
                alive = (current_frame, '0')
            # creates data frame of current frame and count.
            df = pd.DataFrame([alive])
            # Add data frame to next open row in csv file, change accordingly.
            df.to_csv(fr"/home/lm/anaconda3/envs/yolov8_rotiferdetect/CSV_files/exp_{lifespan_number}.csv", index=False, header=False, mode='a')
            # Adds 1 to current_frame to count.
            current_frame +=1
            # Close current image
            img.close()
```